# How to simplify postgres regexp_replace

Tags: regex, postgresql

Is there a way to simplify this query using only one regexp_replace?

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('BL 081', '([^0-9.])', '', 'g'), '(^0+)', '', 'g')
```

> the result should be 81

I'm trying to remove all non-numeric chars and leading 0's from the result

Comment: Your reference method turns 'BL 081-you sunk my battleship-097' into '81097'.  Is that the desired outcome?

Comment: Yes that is just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just change the range from `0-9` to `1-9`?

```
regexp_replace('BL 081', '(^[^1-9]+)', '', 'g')
```

Comment: What if the value is `BL 650`?

Comment: @Nick good point, then with the revision I put it in, that will give 650

Comment: Yeah, this is good although you don't need the enclosing `()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by capturing the digits you want (not including any leading zeros) and removing everything else:

```
select regexp_replace('BL 0081', '.*?([1-9][0-9]*)$', '\1')
```

Output

```
81
```

Note you don't need the `g` flag as you are only making one replacement.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=05170542b794b86f7eaad03656bde190)

Comment: When I run your dbfiddle, I get '1', not '81'.  You need to make the .* non-greedy with a question mark.

Comment: @jjanes thanks for picking that up - I altered the regex slightly and didn't double check the results.

Comment: So instead of replacing everything that is not a number or leading zero with an empty string and using 'g' flag, you are selecting everything that should be in the result with the regex and are using \1 to store the match in the replacement string. Thanks, it works great

Comment: @MyRealNameIsBlaze exactly. You should also check out mikek's answer which might well perform better.

Comment: After testing it mikek's answer does run faster: Execution Time: 9.528 ms vs Execution Time: 33.374 ms

Comment: You should definitely accept @mike.k answer then. I already upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should do: `\D+|(?<=\s)0+`

```
\D - matches characters that are not digits
(?<=\s) - looks behind for spaces and matches leading zeros
```

You can use 1 fewer regexp_replace:

```
select regexp_replace('BL 081', '\D+|(?<=\s)0+', '', 'g')
# outputs 81
```

alternatively, if you are interested in the numeric value, you could use a simpler regex and then cast to an integer.

```
select regexp_replace('BL 081', '\D+', '')::int
# also outputs 81, but its type is int
```